# Salesforce web to case required Fields

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am trying to create a Web to Case form for Salesforce and making custom case fields required. I added the code to the head of my html and it is not working.The form would not submit either.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function checkform (form)
{
var name = document.getElementById('00NC0000005KA85').value;
if (form.name.value == "") {
alert( "Please enter your full name." );form.name.focus();
return false ;
}
return true ;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8"   method="POST" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, however, after reading you have already got the form field value when you did the DOM lookup, that makes the if statement wrong, I believe this may be the correct code:

```
function checkform (form) {
    var name = document.getElementById('00NC0000005KA85');
    if (name.value == "") {
      alert( "Please enter your full name." );
      name.focus();
      return false ;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, are you sure the form field will always have the ID "00NC0000005KA85"? This looks generated, and if the DOM node is missing, again the form will not submit.